# Creating Sencha Touch native app

Tags: extjs

I want to create the native app in sencha touch 2. I have go trough the Sencha Documents and try to create it but I am using the Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.274 and I have tried to run  sencha package run  command on Sencha CMD.

I got the error like,**Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.274 [ERR] Unknown command: "run"**. anybody knows why i got this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your app folder, type:

```
sencha app build native
```

Answer (score 0):

@ neo worked for me..thanks.
    `sencha app build native' created a packager.temp.json 
Then type 
    'sencha app package run'
Its build a native app and opens up ios simulator with the buid app.